# Use of the Spotify Framework Api

Tags: javascript, frameworks, spotify

It's probably my fault, but I can not run the classes in the Framework Api of Spotify

I take the user class as an example (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/api/api-models-user.html)

```
$(function() {
   var sp = getSpotifyApi();
   sp.require(['$api/models'], function(models) {
       var user = models.User.currentUser;
       console.log(user);
   });
 });

// Uncaught TypeError: Object $api/models has no method 'match'
```

or

```
$ (function() {
  var sp = getSpotifyApi();
  var models = sp.require('$api/models');
  models.User.fromURI('spotify:user:1167149818', function(user) {
      console.log(user);
  });

});
// Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function $api/script/models.js: 2142
```

Not work for me.

But I noticed that the classes and methods in this API (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/) work! So I think I missed something.

Could you clear my mind? Thank you!

**EDIT**
According to documentation: 
"Should there only be one call to require module, and it Should be at the top level (not inside another function)."

I tried to put all the code outside of the function, but the result doesn't change

Comment: You have spaces in your string `'$ api / models'`, they don't.

Comment: It's a copy/paste error. That isn't in my code :D

Comment: According to documentation:
"Should there only be one call to require module, and it Should be at the top level (not inside another function)."


I tried to put all the code outside of the function, but the result doesn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple, probably you're using 0.x APIs which were the OLD ones.
To use the new `"require(['blah'])` APIs you have to switch to 1.x APIs and you can find a functional example here: https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/tree/1.0

Try with that, I'm pretty sure it will work :)

**Example of API call**:

```
require(['$api/models'],function(models){
    console.log(models.session.user)
});
```